# How do I implement security groups and user permissions in a single sql table

Tags: sql

I am new to developing SQL tables and permission tables.  The end goal is to use both users and security roles for permissions on forms.  I am unsure of how to go about implementing this in a proper usable and scalable way.

I was attempting to use a single table with a form id, permissions id, bitwise for CRUD, and then an attached user/security id, with one last column detailing if it is a security id or user.  I couldn't come up with a proper way of sorting between whether the permissions are for a security group or a user.

Comment: Hi - what DBMS are using and doesn’t it have a built-in RBAC framework?

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio.  As far as I know, there is no inherent RBAC.